# sveltekit multiple files upload only returns single File

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

i have the following input:

```
<form method="POST" action={`?/${action}`} enctype="multipart/form-data">


  <input
      class="hidden"
      type="file"
      id="images[]"
      name="images[]"
      multiple
  />

</form>
```

on the server side i try to get the multiple files with `.getAll()`

```
const images = data.getAll('images[]') as File[];
console.log(images);
```

it still only gives back **one** File

Comment: a quick test shows the code work, you might need to show some more code, also check in the network tab the outgoing request for any anomalies

Comment: it looks like it works when multiple files are selected at once but not when one is selected after another. i think its because input.files get overwritten. i think the only way to make this work would be to use use:enhance and then manipulate the formdata - right?

Comment: No, this is the expected behaviour of the file input, when doing `multiple` it only allows multiple **at once**, if you click to add another one it will override the previous ones.  To be able to do this you will have to write your own custom logic where you capture the chosen files, add them to a list (akin to attachments in a mail app for example) from where you can remove them.  And then you can use use:enhance to bundle them all up in the request yes

Answer (score -1):

thanks to input from Stephane Vanraes in the comments its now clear that it won't work like this as the input files will be overwritten when the next file is selected.

i managed to get it run with using `use:enhance`, here would be the solution:

create a variable to save the Files selected

```
let imageFiles: File[] = [];
```

create a listener on the on:change event

```
<input
    class="hidden"
    type="file"
    id="hidden"
    name="hidden"
    on:change={handleFiles}
/>
```

save the selected files in the array

```
function handleFiles(event: Event | DragEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

        let eventFiles: FileList | null | undefined = null;

        if (event instanceof DragEvent) {
            eventFiles = event.dataTransfer?.files;
        } else {
            eventFiles = target.files;
        }

        if (!eventFiles) return;

        for (let i = 0; i < eventFiles.length; i++) {
            const file = eventFiles[i];
            imageFiles.push(file);
        }
    }
```

then modify the submit:

```
use:enhance={({ formData, cancel }) => {
        for (const key in imageFiles) {
                formData.append('images[]', imageFiles[key]);
        }
}}
```